# Cocoapods Setup in OS X El Capitan

Tags: cocoapods

**I have issue with cocoapods setup in OS X El Capitan.**

```
Rakeshs-MacBook-Pro:~ rakeshkusuma$ sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

> Successfully installed cocoapods-0.39.0
>
> Parsing documentation for cocoapods-0.39.0
>
> Installing ri documentation for cocoapods-0.39.0
>
> 1 gem installed

```
Rakeshs-MacBook-Pro:~ rakeshkusuma$ pod setup
```

> Setting up CocoaPods master repo
>
> **[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master --depth=1**
>
> **Cloning into 'master'...**
>
> **error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200**
>
> **fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**
>
> **fatal: early EOF**
>
> **fatal: index-pack failed**

---

```
Rakeshs-MacBook-Pro:~ rakeshkusuma$ pod setup --verbose
```

> Setting up CocoaPods master repo
>
> Creating shallow clone of spec repo `master` from
>
> `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
>
> $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
>   --depth=1
>
> Cloning into 'master'...
>
> error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> fatal: early EOF
>
> fatal: index-pack failed
>
> [!] /usr/bin/git clone ttps://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
>   --depth=1
>
> Cloning into 'master'...
>
> error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
>
> fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>
> fatal: early EOF
>
> fatal: index-pack failed
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:70:in
>   `execute_command'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/executable.rb:27:in
>   `block in executable'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/add.rb:74:in
>   `block in clone_repo'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/add.rb:71:in
>   `chdir'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/add.rb:71:in
>   `clone_repo'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/add.rb:43:in
>   `block in run'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in
>   `section'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/add.rb:41:in
>   `run'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-
>   0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/setup.rb:84:in `add_master_repo'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/setup.rb:40:in
>   `block in run'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:59:in
>   `section'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command/setup.rb:32:in
>   `run'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.9.1/lib/claide/command.rb:312:in
>   `run'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:47:in
>   `run'
>
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.39.0/bin/pod:44:in `'
>
> /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
>
> /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `'

Answer (score 0):

You need to change permissions of /usr/local/bin/ . To do that terminal and enter these commands:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
sudo chmod +rx /usr/local/bin/
```

We are uninstalling and reinstalling cocoapods just to be safe, it might not be needed.

Comment: could you please add some further explanation to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Cocoapods instalation in El Capitan: install home brew

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod setup
pod setup --verbose
```

now go to your location of project (CD (your project location) ), after that type `pod init`, it will create a podfile in that location. Open it and give your pod names and write pod install to the same location in terminal.

here you go with the installed pod files!